# Discord bot will not respond, shuts down

Tags: error-handling, crash, discord, discord.js

I am new to programming a Discord bot (and I love it), and it has problems responding. When I start it with `node main.js`, it works as normal until I do something like `-ping`, upon which it stops working.

**Here is the error that I receive:**

```
ReferenceError: clicent is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Eric Müller\Desktop\Discord bot\Main.js:27:9)       
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Eric Müller\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Eric Müller\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)        
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Eric Müller\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Eric Müller\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Eric Müller\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Eric Müller\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\Eric Müller\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '-';
const fs = require('fs');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);

}

client.once('ready', () => {

    console.log('Codelyon is online!');

});

client.on('message', message =>{

if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if(command === 'ping'){

        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);

}
});

client.login('   '); (DISCLAMER! THE TOKEN IS FILLED IN AND CORRECT)
```

**ping.js:**

```
module.exports = {
name: 'ping',
description: "this is a ping command!",
execute(message, args){
message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you most likely have a typo somewhere in your code:

ReferenceError: **clicent** is not defined at Client. (C:\Users\Eric Müller\Desktop\Discord bot\Main.js:27:9)

The error tells you that at the beginning of line 27 in Main.js file, you have clicent, but it was probably supposed to be client.

Comment: @cat_craft In short, clicent is spelt wrong. It's client. You have an extra c. between i and e.